# How to use ffmpeg to overlay waveforms on xstack mosaics and specify specific audio for playback

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I would like to make a mosaic of multiple titled streams, 1) specifying which of the audio streams to play and 2) overlay waveforms at the bottom of each of the video tiles for the audio that they belong to.

I'm successfully able to create the titled mosaic of streams with the code below.

However:

1. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to specify just one of the specific audio sources. I found amix, but I don't really want to mix them, I just want to specify audio [a0], or [a1], or [a2], etc.

and

2. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to overlay the wave forms at the bottom of the video for each of the tiles. I struggled trying to figure out putting showwaves into the mix. Is it possible?

I want each tile to look like this, but since these are rtmp streams, they need to play-out the matching waveforms dynamically with each stream. https://dragonquest64.blogspot.com/2020/01/ffmpeg-audio-waveform.html

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great. I'm getting close, but I'm pretty new to all of this, and have already spent way more time than I should have, so would love a little help.

```
ffmpeg \
-i rtmp://my.cdn.com/srcEncoders/STREAM-1 \
-i rtmp://my.cdn.com/srcEncoders/STREAM-2 \
-i rtmp://my.cdn.com/srcEncoders/STREAM-3 \
-i rtmp://my.cdn.com/srcEncoders/STREAM-4 \
  -filter_complex " \
      [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga \
    , drawtext=text=STREAM-1:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5 [a0]; \
      [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga \
    , drawtext=text=STREAM-2:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5 [a1]; \
      [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga \
    , drawtext=text=STREAM-3:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5 [a2]; \
      [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga \ 
    , drawtext=text=STREAM-4:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5 [a3]; \
      [a0][a1][a2][a3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|0_h0|w0_0|w0_h0[out]; \
    amix=inputs=1
      " \
  -map "[out]" \
 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -g 30 -keyint_min 120 -profile:v baseline -preset veryfast -f mpegts "udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. *Specifying just one of the specific audio stream:* Just use another `-map` option to specify an audio stream just as you are doing with the video stream.
2. *Putting `showwaves` into the mix:* You need a separate filterchain for each of audio inputs.

Below is a rough sketch of the command:

```
ffmpeg \
-i rtmp://my.cdn.com/srcEncoders/STREAM-1 \
-i rtmp://my.cdn.com/srcEncoders/STREAM-2 \
-i rtmp://my.cdn.com/srcEncoders/STREAM-3 \
-i rtmp://my.cdn.com/srcEncoders/STREAM-4 \
  -filter_complex " \
      [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga \
    , drawtext=text=STREAM-1:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5 [a0]; \
      [0:a] showwaves=r=fps:s=wxh[a0w];
      [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga \
    , drawtext=text=STREAM-2:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5 [a1]; \
      [1:a] showwaves=r=fps:s=wxh[a1w];\
      [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga \
    , drawtext=text=STREAM-3:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5 [a2]; \
      [2:a] showwaves=r=fps:s=wxh[a2w];\
      [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga \ 
    , drawtext=text=STREAM-4:fontsize=20:x=10:y=10:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5 [a3]; \
      [3:a]showwaves=r=fps:s=wxh[a3w];\
      [a0][a0w][a1][a1w][a2][a2w][a3][a3w][a3w]\
        xstack=inputs=8:layout=0_0|0_h0|0_h0+h1|0_h0+h1+h2|0_h0+h1+h2+h3|w0_0|w0_h0|w0_h0+h1|w0_h0+h1+h2|w0_h0+h1+h2+h3[out]" \
  -map [out] -map 0:a \
 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -g 30 -keyint_min 120 -profile:v baseline -preset veryfast -f mpegts "udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316"
```

Set the framerate `r` and framesize `s` options of `showwaves` filters to your liking.

For the audio, I just used the first input's, change the stream specifier from `0:a` to select another input

Comment: Many thanks kesh! It's amazing how. much time I spent mucking around with this. I'll give this a shot later tonight!